Replace an unknown string value with NaN in pandas data frame (timestamps) - Python
I am working on a large pandas df with the following format:



Index
Finish




0
01:02:31


1
01:02:31


2
01:02:30


3
01:02:31


4
01:02:31


...
...


311218
NaN


311219
NaN


311220
NaN


311221
NaN


311222
NaN



The type of the column is an object, and when I try to pass it to a time format using:
    `df["Finish"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Finish"])`

I get the following error message: ValueError: symbols w/o a number.
Any idea how I could identify the non-timestamp values ? Some may have been manually typed in as "NA" (or other strings), and some are expressed as 1:02:33.

Add errors='coerce' to to_timedelta:
df["Finish Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Finish Time"], errors='coerce')

If need test problematic values filter rows with added missing values by solution above:
print (df)
       Finish Time
0         01:02:31
1         01:02:31
2         01:02:30
3         01:02:31
4         01:02:31
311218         NaN
311219         NaN
311220         NaN
311221         NaN
311222        data


mask = (pd.to_timedelta(df["Finish Time"], errors='coerce').isna() & 
        df["Finish Time"].notna())
out = df.loc[mask, "Finish Time"]
print (out)
311222    data
Name: Finish Time, dtype: object

So data string is replaced by NaN:
df["Finish Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Finish Time"], errors='coerce')
print (df)
           Finish Time
0      0 days 01:02:31
1      0 days 01:02:31
2      0 days 01:02:30
3      0 days 01:02:31
4      0 days 01:02:31
311218             NaT
311219             NaT
311220             NaT
311221             NaT
311222             NaT

